# Is it possible create war shooter(like Call of duty,Medal of honor etc.) with Udk in one year?

Tags: unreal-development-kit

I don't know UDK,but I'm interested is it possible create war shooter(like Call of Duty,Medal of honor etc.) with Udk in one year with two programmers and one 3D designer?I'm not say as good as Call of Duty or Medal but close to them.

Comment: Maybe... How "big" is this shooter going to be? How many levels? How much content? How much customization? How many cut-scenes? How many hours are available from each resource?

Comment: Full time? Do you have clear and complete Design Document, including detailed descriptions of all levels, gameplay, history, etc? Do you want to achieve the same Detail per Model that call of duty or you just mean the gameplay?

Comment: ...also, I think there's a StackExchange site for game development... (sorry but I can't remember the URL) ...but I don't think we can migrate directly to there. Anyone know the URL ?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For what it's worth I doubt you can come anywhere near the scale / complexity or polish of Call of Duty with 2 programmers and 1 designer.  These modern games have entire armies of developers/artists etc - look at the credits http://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare/credits

Comment: Yes full time.Game must be not small,and graphic must really good.There is some conception of the game and history.

Answer (score 6):

As someone working in the games industry, I would say no. There is a good reason for multiple year development cycles with those teams. Call of Duty games take 2 years to develop even with large teams like Treyarch (around 250 employees).

It's not simply creating tons and tons of content, but making it all fit together, and all the dependencies between things going in. Like you can't start scripting up encounters until you have a level blocked out, and you can't start adding effects to weapons if the weapon isn't in game. You can't localize the text or dialog until it's finalized. A lot of that also depends on new tech from the engineering team. Etc etc etc.

That's all independent of what engine you choose to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

It is an extremely ambitious goal but if you are all working full time on this you could get something of middling quality in that time. It may be buggy and/or unoriginal but it *could* be done.

No chance of it being anywhere near the quality of the mentioned games though.

Comment: note the emphesis on could. It will likely not be what you may be expecting if you don't get frustrated by process and quit beforehand. Why the 1 year limit?

Comment: I  say one year as approximately time that I thought It would  be possible to do.

Answer (score 2):

Umm of course you can do it, 3 ppl army to build a whole game, well... I will suggest you one thing, scrap cinematics, get rid off nonsense levels and cut to the cheese, thats whats most of the hard gamers look for, no fancy cinematics, straight to the action point. 
    In my opinion a good multiplayer game mode will do the trick as ,,, per now.. and wait fot the feedback, maybe if your game is good enough you can hire more staff, and work on the 1 player side. So cut to the cheese, and straight to the action, thats my opinion according to the amount of ppl involved in your game development. And many guys here will tell you,, ohh noo you cant get the same level of quality as COD, gee man of course you cant, thats obvious,,3 against 100's no chance, but what it is important is the idea, you have a good idea, put it on paper and then on your game. Dont go crazy and try to create the whole thing, theres no physical time for you 3 guys working 24/7 to finish this off in a year. So, start little with good visual texturing, then go from there. I hope you guys do well.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays that might be almost impossible. I work at Treyarch, and while I can't say much details, here are the basics:

1. You need QA - just this, and your quest is over. And this is only to test your game play, logic, whether a level can be completed, etc.
2. You need even more QA, for things you've never expected - certification (Xbox, PS3, Nintendo), localization (language, censorship, etc)

You need production team. Very motivated and goal oriented.

You need programmers, artists, animators, builders, scripters.

You put at least one person behind every profession, and you need at minimum 10 people. That would've been fine 15 years ago. Unfortunately not now.

People can still do it. There's been some game development of 9 people of sci-fi robots game using UDK (can't remember the name of the game) - but this means engine is provided, and the people have very good motivation, and probably are very good themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can...the art assets won't be as good though

Answer (score 0):

If you were to purchase your assets (3D models, open source engine, pre-made textures) then I suspect this could be all put together if you guys coded in only the fundamental parts of the game that make it yours.

The question is how much do you want to have commercialy bought versus homegrown and implemented